# Help with a bungee jumping question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, spring

Hi I have this question:

Imagine that you have been given the job of desiging a new bungee jumping platform. Customers of mass 57.4 kg will step off a platform, attached to a rope of unstretched length 45.3 m and spring constant 29.9 n/m.

How far below the platform will the end of end of the rope get during a jump? This is the lowest point it will ever reach, not where it settles down.

You may assume that g=9.8 m s-2.

But I have no idea how to solve it.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks. if you can please try to show how you got the answer step by step.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! We encourage to ask about concepts you don't understand. [Homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) focuses to pose questions, helping to understand a broader scope than just the one question. Once a concept is understood, you are given the oportunity to answer similar questions by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

An idealized solution of the problem is quite easy.

The jumper falls until the rope pulls tight and brings the jumper to rest. At this point the rope's length is the sum of its unstretched length $l$ plus the stretched length $s$. The potential energy corresponding to the length $l+s$ has been converted into potential energy stored in the stretch $s$ of the rope. Setting both energies equal lets you calculate $s$.

Comment: ok, does that give you that the s (the length of the stretch) = Sqrt(2mgh/k) because I've tried that and apparently its wrong.

Comment: Did you calculate the potential energy with the length of the stretched rope?